# Return two vectors – use reference or tuple?

Tags: c++, c++17

What is better to use for return two initialized vectors? I remember that few years ago was better to use passing a reference and change it inside function to avoid copy a value but I'm not sure how it is nowadays in C++17 and a copy elision.

Example:

```
void sample1(vector<string>& v1, vector<string>& v2) {
    for (auto i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
        v1.push_back(random_string(10));
        v2.push_back(random_string(10));
    }
}

tuple<vector<string>, vector<string>> sample2() {
    vector<string> v1, v2;
    for (auto i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
        v1.push_back(random_string(10));
        v2.push_back(random_string(10));
    }
    return { std::move(v1), std::move(v2) };
}

int main() {
    {
        std::vector<std::string> v1, v2;
        sample1(v1, v2);
    }
    {
        auto [v1, v2] = sample2();
    }

}
```

Is there any difference in a performance between sample1 and sample2? I measured and both takes around 16 seconds on my machine so I suppose there is no difference because the copy constructor is not called in second example. If I remove std::move, then sample2 is slower by ca. 3 seconds

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you could speed up the functions quite considerably by reserving memory for the vectors beforehand. :)

Comment: @some It's related to the question. Reserving memory beforehand would reduce that huge allocation time and give any difference between the two return types the ability to shine through. Jon if you do find that there's no real difference between the two, then I recommend using whichever one helps you be more consistent across the rest of your code. tuple returns or reference returns seem to be mostly a style thing.

Comment: Okay, thank you guys a lot :) I thought that.

Answer (score 2):

There's no universal answer.

Returning is more convenient. You don't have to think about previous content, you have less lines of code on caller side. It is more idiomatic, after all.

But if the function would be called in a loop, then reference version allows memory to be reserved just once, not on each function call (by using the same vectors as output).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use `std::pair` for returning two vectors. I think the common programming style is to pass input parameters by const reference and for outputs use function return value, e.g. something like this:

```
outputs = f(input params)
```

With this style, it is much easier to find out input parameters and the output value of every function from its declaration. In addition, standard library uses this style when it needs to have two outputs for a function. One example is the `std::set::insert`:

```
std::pair<iterator,bool> insert( const value_type& value )
```